# What vim plugins mix results in this interface

Tags: python, ide, plugins, vim

I saw this VIM UI and thought it was awesome and now I want it. Anyone know what plugins the author is using?

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/wiki30/files/wiki30.mp4

Comment: It seems all of pocoo.org is having issues since last night.  From memory, Armin had an old blog post about his setup.  He uses fruity.vim as his colorscheme, that's about the only specific I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit dated, but this is his blog post that I was referring to: [Vim as Development Environment](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2007/4/2/vim-as-development-environment)